# Python: error when plot loglog with -nun values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a plot in log-log scale but some columns in my file contain -nun values which give me an error message:

> "ValueError: Data has no positive values, and therefore can not be log-scaled."

My question is how can I solve this?

Note that, I tried t use the argument `"nonposy="clip"` to solve it but it didn't work.

Example of the file contains

```
tau DDM DDMerr n_pairs
3.00 -nan -nan 0
3.75 -nan -nan 0
4.69 -nan -nan 0
5.86 4.997519e-09 7.082515e-09 1
7.32 3.943581e-07 9.197634e-09 59
9.16 1.466947e-06 3.455545e-07 1
```

The code:

```
Data = numpy.loadtxt(sf_file)
tau = Data[:,0]
DDM = Data[:,1]
DDM_err = Data[:,2]
n_pairs = Data[:,3]


#Kolmogorov
kolm= (tau)**(5./3.)

fig=plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xscale('log', nonposy="clip")
ax.set_yscale('log', nonposy="clip")
plt.errorbar(tau, DDM, DDM_err, label= "SF", marker='o', ms=7, color='magenta')
plt.plot(tau, kolm, color='g',linewidth=2,label='Kolmogorov')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your code seem to be working fine for me on matplotlib 3.0.0.

Comment: Humm, for now, I'm commenting the rows which contain the -nun values manually to be able to process my task! which not what I was looking for. There should be a way to avoid this within the plotting itself!

Comment: Thanks, sorry, it's working! very late reply from me.